# How can I extend Lisa's taskbar across both monitors?

Tags: linux-mint, gnome3, gnome-shell

I've just installed Linux Mint 12 Lisa and would like to extend the bottom taskbar to both monitors.

Lisa uses a fork of Gnome Shell (Gnome 3) called [Cinnamon](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cinnamon 1.8 does not yet support extending or duplicating the taskbar to multiple monitors. There is an [open issue on github](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/130) with some support, but no progress yet as far as I am aware.

For extended taskbar support on Linux, see [The State of Linux Dual Monitor Support](http://jonblack.org/2013/06/02/the-state-of-linux-dual-monitor-support/).

Comment: [The State of Linux Dual Monitor Support](http://jonblack.org/2013/06/02/the-state-of-linux-dual-monitor-support/) The link does not work anymore.